# how to create new plugin for jqplot -option?

Tags: jqplot, label, series, gantt-chart

I've added just a few lines to the jqplot.pointlabels.js file so I get an extra option in the jqplot pointlabels option. How do I make a new plugin for that?

Of course I like to keep those changes if I need to update. I'm not sure how to do this. I'm trying to make a timeline / Gantt like graph. Each item or line piece is a series with just two points. So instead of having pointlabels at each end, I calculate the center and place just one label.

So in jqplot.pointlabels.js, line 322 would be:

```
            if (p.centerLabel) {
                var ell =  xax.u2p(pd[i][0]) + ((xax.u2p(pd[1][0]) - xax.u2p(pd[0][0])) / 2) +p.xOffset(elem, location);
            } else {
                var ell = xax.u2p(pd[i][0]) + p.xOffset(elem, location);    
            }
```

and in the options of jqplot I would write something like:

```
  pointLabels:{
              show:true,
              location:'s',
              fontSize: '1em',
              centerLabel: true, // extra option, see code
              labelsFromSeries: true,
              formatter: $.jqplot.DefaultTickFormatter,
          }
```

I could copy all the code to a new plugin called jqplot.singleSeriesLabels.js but how do I get jqplot to use that plugin for the 'pointLabels'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a simpel sollution:
I copied the complete plugin to a new file and just changed the plugin name like so

```
$.jqplot.newPluginName = function(options) {
```

On the site where I used to set the options for the pointLabels plugin, I now do the same but with the new name:

```
newPluginName:{
          show:true,
          location:'s',
          fontSize: '1em',
          centerLabel: true, // extra option, see code
          labelsFromSeries: true,
          formatter: $.jqplot.DefaultTickFormatter,
      }
```

Don't forget to include the new plugin-file on your site